# Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA) plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the results of Iris dataset Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA) using MASS and ggplot2 packages. The script show in its first part, the Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) but I but I do not know to continue to do it for the QDA. The objects of class "qda" are a bit different from the "lda" class objects, for example: I can not find the Proportion of trace/X% of explained between-group Variance/discriminant components and can not add them to the graph axes. Any help or ideas how to code this graph using ggplot2?

Code:

```
require(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
 

irislda <- lda(Species ~ ., iris)
prop.lda = irislda$svd^2/sum(irislda$svd^2)
plda <- predict(irislda,   iris)

datasetLDA = data.frame(species = iris[,"Species"], irislda = plda$x)
ggplot(datasetLDA) + geom_point(aes(irislda.LD1, irislda.LD2, colour = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
    labs(x = paste("LD1 (", percent(prop.lda[1]), ")", sep=""),
       y = paste("LD2 (", percent(prop.lda[2]), ")", sep=""))

 
irisqda <- qda(Species ~ ., iris)
pqda <- predict(irisqda,   iris)
datasetQDA = data.frame(species = iris[,"Species"], irisqda = pqda$posterior) 
ggplot(datasetQDA) + geom_point(???, ???, colour = species, shape = species), size = 2.5)
```

Comment: Please check this https://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/viz_classifier.html posterior probabilities can be plotted in order to see the distribution for each class!

Comment: I did not see any information about Quadratic Discriminant Analysis in the HTML page.

Answer (score 12):

Following Ducks comment, if you have only 2 dimensions we can use the `decisionplot` function provided in the link to visualize these. It has to be altered slightly for more variables.

```
library(MASS)
model <- qda(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, iris)
decisionplot(model, iris, class = "Species")
```

[image: base plot]

The `decisionplot` function is shown below.

```
decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
  resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {

  if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
  data <- data[,1:2]
  k <- length(unique(cl))

  plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)

  # make grid
  r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
  xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
  ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
  g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
  colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
  g <- as.data.frame(g)

  ### guess how to get class labels from predict
  ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
  p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
  if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
  p <- as.factor(p)

  if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")

  z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
  contour(xs, ys, z, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE,
    lwd = 2, levels = (1:(k-1))+.5)

  invisible(z)
}
```

If we wanted to recreate this with `ggplot2` we'd simply have to change the function to utilize `ggplot2` functions rather than base plots. This entails changing the data into `data.frame`s and building the plot along the way.

```
decisionplot_ggplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
  
  if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
  data <- data[,1:2]
  cn <- colnames(data)
  
  k <- length(unique(cl))
  
  data$pch <- data$col <- as.integer(cl) + 1L
  gg <- ggplot(aes_string(cn[1], cn[2]), data = data) + 
    geom_point(aes_string(col = 'as.factor(col)', shape = 'as.factor(col)'), size = 3)
  
  # make grid
  r <- sapply(data[, 1:2], range, na.rm = TRUE)
  xs <- seq(r[1, 1], r[2, 1], length.out = resolution)
  ys <- seq(r[1, 2], r[2, 2], length.out = resolution)
  
  g <- cbind(rep(xs, each = resolution), 
             rep(ys, time = resolution))
  colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
  
  g <- as.data.frame(g)
  
  ### guess how to get class labels from predict
  ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
  p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
  if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
  g$col <- g$pch <- as.integer(as.factor(p)) + 1L
  
  if(showgrid) 
    gg <- gg + geom_point(aes_string(x = cn[1], y = cn[2], col = 'as.factor(col)'), data = g, shape = 20, size = 1)
  
  gg + geom_contour(aes_string(x = cn[1], y = cn[2], z = 'col'), data = g, inherit.aes = FALSE)
}
```

Usage:

```
decisionplot_ggplot(model, iris, class = "Species")
```

Note it now returns the ggplot itself, so one could use standard functions to change the title, theme etc. Also this is simply a direct translation. Using `geom_polygon` with a valid `alpha` would likely be more visually pleasing. Similar better contours could be made with an alternative choice of `geom_*`.
[image: ggplot]

Answer (score 2):

Adding to my own answer, as I stated (for cases where `npar > 2`)

> It has to be altered slightly for more variables.

One would have to choose how to do this. One method would be to use the `mean` or numeric variables and base level of `factor`s, eg. holding these at a constant level, while plotting the remaining variables. This seemed somewhat interesting for the question, as the example given had more than 2 variables.

We can alter the `decisionplot_ggplot` function (quite substantially) in order to obtain this, while letting the user specify variables to be plotted through a new argument `vars`, while keeping the usage very similar to the previous function definition

```
#' Create a decisionplot using the ggplot package.
#'
#' @param model any model 
#' @param vars either a character vector of length 2, or a formula of form V1 ~ V2 specifying y and x axis of the plot respectively.
#' @param data data to use for visualization. Should contain all the data needed to use the model
#' @param resolution number of points to use for visualizetion.
#' @param showgrid logical, should areas of classes be coloured?
#' @param ... further parameters passed to predict
#' @param modes.means levels use for plotting the variables not specified in vars.
decisionplot_ggplot <- function(model, 
                                vars, 
                                data, 
                                resolution = 100,
                                showgrid = TRUE, 
                                ...,
                                modes.means) {
  if(missing(model) || missing(vars) || missing(data))
    stop('model, vars or data is missing')
  if(!(is.character(vars) && length(vars) == 2) && !('formula' %in% class(vars) && length(vars <- all.vars(vars)) == 2))
    stop('vars should be either a formula or a character vector oflength 2.')
  if(!is.data.frame(data))
    stop('data does not seem to comform with standard types.')
  
  t <- terms(model)
  if(!all((other.vars <- attr(t, 'term.labels')) %in% colnames(data)))
    stop('data is missing one or more variables in model.')
  lhs <- as.character(t[[2]])
  # Set up data for prediction, for the data in vars
  prd.vars <- lapply(data[, vars], function(x){
    if(is.character(x) || is.factor(x)){
      unique(x)
    }else{
      r <- range(x)
      seq(r[1], r[2], length.out = resolution)
    }
  })
  names(prd.vars) <- vars
  # set up data for prediction for the remaining data
  if(missing(modes.means)){
    other.vars <- other.vars[!other.vars %in% vars]
    if(length(other.vars)){
      modes.means <- lapply(data[, other.vars], function(x){
        if(is.character(x)){
          unique(x)[1]
        }else if(is.factor(x)){
          levels(x)[1]
        }else{
          mean(x)
        }
      }) 
      names(modes.means) <- other.vars
    }else
      modes.means <- NULL
  }else{
    if(is.null(other.vars))
      stop('other.vars is null but modes.means was provided. Please leave this missing.')
    if(!all(other.vars %in% names(modes.means)))
      stop('modes.means are lacking one or more variables.')
    modes.means <- as.list(modes.means)
    if(any(lengths(modes.means) > 1))
      stop('modes.means should only contain a single values for all variables.')
  }
  prd.data <- expand.grid(c(prd.vars, modes.means))
  p <- predict(model, prd.data, ...)
  prd.data$nm <- if(is.list(p)) 
    p$class 
  else 
    p
  names(prd.data)[ncol(prd.data)] <- lhs
  # Create the final plot.
  gg <- ggplot(aes_string(vars[1], vars[2]), data = data) + 
    geom_point(aes_string(col = lhs, shape = lhs), size = 3) + 
    geom_contour(aes_string(vars[1], vars[2], z = paste0('as.integer(', lhs, ') + 1L')), data = prd.data, inherit.aes = FALSE)
  if(showgrid)
    gg <- gg + 
      geom_point(aes_string(vars[1], vars[2], col = lhs), data = prd.data, shape = 20, size = 0.5)
  gg
}
```

Now the added flexibility of this function allows us to plot some more complex models

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
model <- qda(Species ~ ., iris)
decisionplot_ggplot(model, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris, showgrid = TRUE)
```

[image: multivariate-decisionplot]

One thing to be very aware of however, is that this plot is very sensitive to the chosen values for the variables, that are **not** included in the plot itself. For example the following is not a very useful plot.

```
decisionplot_ggplot(model, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, iris, showgrid = TRUE)
```

[image: bad-multivariate-decisionplot]

What we see here is that the average value of `Petal.Length` clearly has a huge impact on whether or not the model classifies an observation as `setosa`. And as this is held constant, we've lost a lot of our classification power.

This should very clearly indicate the obvious, that one we move past models with 2 parameters decision boundary plots are very hard to visualize in any useful manner. Personally I'd discourage using decision boundary plots outside the simple models.