# Unable to plot my QDA classification method

Tags: r, classification

I have created a few types of classification, but when performing QDA I'm am unable to plot my predictions, does anyone know how to predict this?

```
set.seed(20220719)
#splitting training and testing data
ii = createDataPartition(classification[,3], p = .75, list = F)
```

training = classification[ii, ] #predictors for training
testing = classification[-ii, ] #predictors for testing

```
#fitting the model
qda_mod = qda(Group ~., training)

#predicting testing data
p2 = predict(qda_mod, testing)$class
tab1 = table(Predicted = p2, Actual = testing$Group)
tab1
```

data snipet

```
classification
             X1           X2 Group
1   -1.007927175  0.399027128     0
2   -0.472479667  0.839121791     1
3    0.745229326 -1.279741933     1
4   -0.597907906 -1.942435976     1
5    0.186984091 -1.541910328     1
6   -0.395736986 -0.120650487     1
7   -0.155861012  1.193432933     0
8    0.382043985 -1.700433181     1
9    0.684346226 -0.890674936     1
10   0.453268993  0.674205724     1
```

Looking for an output similar to;

[image]

Comment: Is this all your data, or do you have some more samples?

Comment: @Quinten All of the data can be accessed here; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GYnlsXgT2GS9ubeXq8Pm7iNUWDRGogU_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Predicted groups have been colored with actual classification with red and green color. These are extracted from your `predict` call. The mix of red and green colors in groups shows the incorrect classification prediction. You can use the following code:

```
library(caret)
library(MASS)
set.seed(20220719)
#splitting training and testing data
ii = createDataPartition(classification[,3], p = .75, list = F)

training = classification[ii, ] #predictors for training 
testing = classification[-ii, ] #predictors for testing

#fitting the model
qda_mod = qda(Group ~., training)

#predicting testing data
p2 = predict(qda_mod, testing)
#tab1 = table(Predicted = p2, Actual = testing$Group)
#tab1

# plot
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(p2$posterior[,2], p2$class, col=testing$Group+10)
```

Output:

[image]

For extra info check this [link](https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-perform-logistic-regression-lda-qda-in-r/).

@Oliver, made some nice functions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782598/quadratic-discriminant-analysis-qda-plot-in-r). Maybe this helps:

```
decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
  
  if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
  data <- data[,1:2]
  k <- length(unique(cl))
  
  plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)
  
  # make grid
  r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
  xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
  ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
  g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
  colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
  g <- as.data.frame(g)
  
  ### guess how to get class labels from predict
  ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
  p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
  if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
  p <- as.factor(p)
  
  if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")
  
  z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
  contour(xs, ys, z, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE,
          lwd = 2, levels = (1:(k-1))+.5)
  
  invisible(z)
}

decisionplot(qda_mod, training, class = "Group")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry my poor question, i was looking for the output to be similar to my initial grid (i have updated this now in the question).  This was using ggplot and geom_raster

Comment: Hi @Joe, No problem! I added some code with a nice post that maybe helps.